# Bad Company 2 modes

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2

Is someone able to confirm for me (or whatever) if that new mode that was only coming out for consoles is also coming to PC...? Cos it would be nice if it did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not confirmed](http://twitter.com/zh1nt0/status/18503035016)

> The article published by PC-Gamer is
>   not accurate. We are currently
>   researching if Onslaught will be
>   available for PC. No release date.